# How to auto activate python virtual environment when opening project folder in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I have Python v3.9 installed in Windows 10. Also have VS Code 1.55.0

I created a new folder ('MyProject') and placed a .ipynb file in there. Then created a virtual environment 'proj_env' inside MyProject. I can manually activate the venv, but can't get it to auto-launch when opening folder MyProject.

settings.json file contents:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "proj_env\\Scripts\\python.exe",
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you create this virtual environment in VS Code? In VS Code, it defaults to use the python environment before it was closed last time. For the virtual environment in VS Code, please refer to: [Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: I set up the virtual env in VS Code using following commands:  `python -m venv proj_env` followed by `proj_env\Scripts\activate.bat`. Then I edited the settings.json file as shown in OP. If I manually launch the venv using activate.bat, then exit VS Code, then relaunch VS Code and open this project, the venv is NOT automatically activated. I have to run activate.bat or use CTRL+SHIFT+P to select it.

Comment: -Do you mean that the virtual environment is not automatically displayed in the lower left corner of VS Code or the VS Code terminal? For the VS Code terminal, please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new terminal, it will automatically activate the selected environment.

Comment: Both - venv is not displayed in lower left corner of VS Code or in the terminal. Using CTRL+SHIFT+` does open a new terminal, but that terminal is not running the virtual environment.

Comment: -Have you tried other virtual environments? Please try to create a new virtual environment in VS Code and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, VS Code is now behaving as expected - when I open the folder with settings.json file as described in OP, the virtual env is launched (venv displayed in lower left corner), and opening a new terminal activates the venv.

Only change I can think of is that I recently restarted my computer (usually go a week or two between restarts). I had restarted VS Code multiple times while I was having this issue, but that didn't resolve issue.

I can't be certain that restarting PC was the solution, but it's my best guess. Next time issue appears, I will try exiting/restarting VSCode, and if that doesn't resolve, I'll restart PC and see if that resolves, and will post back here.

Thanks @JillCheng for helping me out!